# What is the time format in chrome dev tools cache Expires/ Max-Age?

Tags: time, timezone, google-chrome-devtools, utc

I noticed the time format in chrome cache expiry is in format of 2021-06-19T08:38:40.980Z.
I do not recognize this time format and cant find about its conversion to UTC. So, my question is what kind of time format is this one. And how to convert it to UTC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) extended date time format.  It also conforms to the [RFC 3339](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339) timestamp format, and the [ECMAScript date time string format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format).  Basically, that's the standard, most preferred way to represent a timestamp (as a string) on the Internet.

- The date part is in `yyyy-MM-dd` format (year, month, day).
- The `T` stands for "Time" and separates the date part from the time part.
- The time is in `HH:mm:ss.fff` format (hour of 24-hour clock, minute, seconds, fractional seconds - milliseconds in this case).
- The `Z` stands for "Zulu", another name for UTC.  It indicates that the date and time before it are represented in UTC.

Thus, you do not need to convert it.  The value is *already* in UTC.

Comment: Thank you. That has answered my Question!